# Paging with php without using limit syntax

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, limit, paging

I just wanna ask if that's possible, and if it is, how ? because I'm running out of ideas.  my query only get 1 record at the time so the limit didn't work for me.
I'm making a searchbar function, with 4 tables using union . 
here's the code

```
if (isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] !=""){
$searchquery = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '' , $_POST['searchquery']);
$radio = $_POST['radio'];


 $sqlcommand = "(SELECT id_fakultas as id_search
FROM tabel_fakultas
WHERE kode_fakultas LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR ket_fakultas LIKE '%$searchquery%')


UNION 

(SELECT id_jenis AS id_search
FROM tabel_jenis
WHERE jenis_surat LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR ket_jenis LIKE '%$searchquery%')

UNION 

(SELECT id_kodearea as id_search
FROM tabel_kodearea
WHERE kode_area LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR ket_kodearea LIKE '%$searchquery%')

UNION 

(SELECT id_lembaga as id_search
FROM tabel_lembaga
WHERE kode_lembaga LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR ket_lembaga LIKE '%$searchquery%')

UNION 

(SELECT id_prodi as id_search
FROM tabel_prodi
WHERE kode_prodi LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR ket_prodi LIKE '%$searchquery%')

UNION

(SELECT id_surat AS id_search
FROM tabel_surat
WHERE 

 subyeksurat LIKE '%$searchquery%'
OR tanggal_srtmasuk LIKE '%$searchquery%'
OR tanggal_srtkeluar LIKE '%$searchquery%'
OR keterangan LIKE '%$searchquery%'
OR no_surat LIKE '%$searchquery%'
OR status_surat LIKE '%$searchquery%'
AND tipe_surat LIKE '%$searchquery%'

)


";

$runquery = mysql_query($sqlcommand)or die(mysql_error());

$query_jumlah = mysql_num_rows ($runquery);
```

so whatever I'm typing , it'll check the id which match with those 4 tables. after I get the id , I'll use it to get the record I wanted. it's on 4th table .

```
if ( $query_jumlah > 0 )
                                    { 


                                                while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($runquery)){ 

                                                $cari = $data['id_search'];


                                                echo $posisi, $batas;
                                                $commandcari = mysql_query("SELECT 
                    tfak.kode_fakultas, tfak.ket_fakultas,
                    tj.jenis_surat, tj.ket_jenis, 
                    tk.kode_area , tk.ket_kodearea, 
                    tlem.kode_lembaga, tlem.ket_lembaga,
                    tprodi.kode_prodi, tprodi.ket_prodi, 
                    ts.tipe_surat, ts.subyeksurat, ts.tanggal_srtmasuk, ts.tanggal_srtkeluar, ts.keterangan, ts.no_surat, ts.status_surat,
                    ts.id_surat, ts.id_fakultas, ts.id_jenis, ts.id_lembaga, ts.id_prodi, ts.tipe_surat, ts.file
                    FROM tabel_surat ts 
                    LEFT JOIN tabel_jenis tj 
                    ON ts.id_jenis=tj.id_jenis 
                    LEFT JOIN tabel_kodearea tk 
                    ON ts.id_kodearea=tk.id_kodearea 
                    LEFT JOIN tabel_lembaga tlem 
                    ON ts.id_lembaga=tlem.id_lembaga
                    LEFT JOIN tabel_prodi tprodi 
                    ON ts.id_prodi=tprodi.id_prodi
                    LEFT JOIN tabel_fakultas tfak 
                    ON ts.id_fakultas=tfak.id_fakultas 


                    WHERE  
                     ts.id_surat LIKE '%$cari%' 

                    OR ts.id_lembaga LIKE '%$cari%'
                    OR ts.id_fakultas LIKE '%$cari%'
                    OR ts.id_prodi LIKE '%$cari%'
                    AND ts.tipe_surat LIKE '%$radio%' 
                    LIMIT $posisi,$batas

                     ") or die(mysql_error());


                                                if(mysql_num_rows($commandcari) > 0 ) { 
                                                $no1 =$posisi+1;
                                                    while ($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($commandcari)) { 
                                                    $no++;
                                                    $pembuat_fakultas=$data2['id_fakultas'];
                                    $pembuat_lembaga=$data2['id_lembaga'];
                                    $pembuat_prodi=$data2['id_prodi'];
                                    echo '
                                                        <tr> 

                                                    <td align="center"> '.$no.'</td>
                                    <td align="center"> '.$data2['no_surat'].'</td>
                                    <td align="center"> '.$data2['jenis_surat'].'</td>
                                    <td align="center"> '.$data2['subyeksurat'].'</td>
                                    <td align="center"> '.$data2['ket_jenis'].'</td>
                                    <td align="center"> '.$data2['kode_area'].'</td>';
                                                if ($pembuat_fakultas!=''){
                                                echo '<td align="center"> '.$data2['ket_fakultas'].'</td>' ; }
                                                elseif ($pembuat_lembaga !=''){
                                                echo '<td align="center"> '.$data2['ket_lembaga'].'</td>' ; }
                                                elseif ($pembuat_prodi != ''){
                                                echo '<td align="center"> '.$data2['ket_prodi'].'</td>' ; }

                                                if ($radio!='suratkeluar'){
                                                echo '<td align="center"> '.$data2['tanggal_srtmasuk'].'</td>';}
                                                elseif ($radio!='suratmasuk'){
                                                echo '<td align="center"> '.$data2['tanggal_srtkeluar'].'</td>';}




                    echo'
                                    <td align="center"> '.$data2['keterangan'].'</td>
                                    <td align="center"><a href="'.$data2['file'].'" target = "_blank"> Preview</a></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                ';




                                    }




                                    }

                                    } 

                    }
```

if I use the usual paging, with LIMIT in my mysql_query , my row only returned 1. It's because I only get the id from the union  and see which record use the id I got from the union on the 4th table . so if I got 3 ids from the union, like ID1, ID2, ID3, when I use it on $commandcari, it'll return 1 record num row on each id.

```
select * from tabel_surat where id_surat = id1
select * from tabel_surat where id_surat = id2
select * from tabel_surat where id_surat = id3
```

is it possible to do the pagination without using limit ?

NB : I know my english is not good enough to do the explanation (it's not my primary language), but I hope you understand my question.

Comment: You can always wrap your full query to `SELECT * FROM (SELECT...) t LIMIT x, y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need pagination on a search in multiple tables, then you need to get all result records from the 4 tables and do the pagination on the client side. Ie.

- assume page size is 10
- get all data returns 15 records
- If page > 1 then throw away the first (page-1)*pagesize records
- loop through 10 records unless there are no further records - ie. page 2 you only have 5 records.

Print pagination links as normal